# extract width and text between dots from an image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, python-tesseract

i am trying to extract data from an image of room plan. top side of this image contains *widths* of specific parts of room.

[image]

•-------- 885 --------•-------- 1,555 --------•-------- 1,960 --------• etc...

so for example I want to extract the number of 2,365 and also extract that numbers px width of between dots. actually I don't want to extract all numbers. just want to get one, it doesn't matter which.

I managed to get the numbers by the below code.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract


from pytesseract import Output


image = cv2.imread(image_path)
height, width, _ = image.shape

data = pytesseract.image_to_data(image, config=config, output_type=Output.DICT)
box_count = len(data["text"])

for i in range(box_count):
  if float(data["conf"][i]) > 70:
    (x, y, width, height) = (data["left"][i], data["top"][i], data["width"][i], data["height"][i])
    image = cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + width, y + height), (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow("img", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

but not very sure how to get width of between dots if I select a number. let's say I got the **1,960** and now I want its px width of between two dots. How can achieve this.

```
•-------- 1,960 --------•
```

expected output: `[1960, "200px"]`

Comment: so you should find these dots, yes?

Comment: yes, correct. I think first I get the number, then the dots, but I am not sure how to find dots @ChristophRackwitz

Comment: could be done with morphology operations (open or close), which will remove the thin lines, but leave the dots and text standing. now you would use connectedComponentsWithStats, or findContours, and only keep those contours that are small and compact (pixel area is close to bounding box area).

Comment: Well, if you're already using OpenCV, you might consider [template matching](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html) to find the dots.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz also will check on that too. thank you.